# Web service using php soap server and java client

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, soap-client

*I want to learn to implement web services using soap in php. I also want to utilize the service using java client. I am interested in soap protocol and if there is some othere better protocol.*

**My research:** I got many online tutorials on implementing web service using soap in php. I also got greate content on soap protocol.

**My question:** How to utilize that service using java client? Is it possible? Can you refer me to tutorial which serves my need? Is there any good book that i can purchase. I also want to know how can a php soap server authenticate a java client. Is authentication done for each request or maintaining session is possible.

Comment: So you did not find any tutorial telling you how to implement a Java based SOAP client?

Comment: @home: yes i did not find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition:

> Web Services have been designed to support interoperable Machine to
>   Machine interaction over a network.

So consuming a web service is independent of the implementation technology of the web service, now you can search for "implement a Java based SOAP client" on SO.

plus check below URLs:

[Java Client – PHP Soapserver](http://development.nedeco.de/blog/2011/08/03/java-client-php-soapserver/)

And [THIS](http://www.ksi.edu/thesis/rhuang/rhuang.pdf) free book by Nan-Chao Huang.